# PHP replace substring of varying length

Tags: php, string, substr

I'm looking to replace a substring with a new value of varying length.  I've got a vague grasp on substr_replace, but it's leaving extra characters if the relacement string is shorter than the original.

The basic string I need to edit looks something like this

```
In Target(+-50%): <span style="color: red">33%</span>(1/3)<br>
```

I need to replace everything after the closing > of the span tag and before the opening < of the br tag. However, the number of characters will vary.

For Example: the string I want to remove is "33%(1/3)" which is 7 characters.  I want to replace it with "9%(9/100)" which is 16 characters.  I don't want to overwrite the br tag.

This seems like it should be simple, but I can't get my head around it.  Should I be looking at preg_replace?

Comment: You'll need regex to do that...

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos Now you have two problems.  Just kidding :)

Comment: Is your target string actually `33%(1/3)`, or the HTML you've quoted? They are two *very* different problems, please clarify which is the case.

Comment: @Sammitch The target string is the text as listed including the closing span tag, I need to manipulate that space specifically.  Although I could do multiple replacements if using the </span> as an anchor point would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$subject = 'In Target(+-50%): <span style="color: red">33%</span>(1/3)<br>';
$pattern = '/<span\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/span>(.*?)<br>/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
$subject = str_replace($matches[1][0], 'REPLACE WITH THIS TEXT', $subject);
$subject = str_replace($matches[2][0], 'REPLACE SECOND PART WITH THIS TEXT', $subject);

print_r($subject);
?>
```

Comment: That looks good, I think I'll be able to work with this.  Thanks

Comment: If there were multiple occurances of the $pattern in $subject, why doesn't $matches contain all the hits?  Do I need to re-run preg_match with a new offset?

Comment: Now I'm running into conditions where $matches[1][0] shows up elsewhere in my $subject (it's longer than I listed). How can I replace the specific text just in the matched areas?

Answer (score -1):

This should separate what you need:

```
preg_match('#(<span[^>]*>)(\d+\%)(</span>)(\(\d+/\d+\))#', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Then you can use `str_replace` with the matches.

Comment: Your regex is to specific, what if the first value is a decimal or the last number is not a fraction?

Comment: Dude, look at the sample string OP posted. I could say your regex is too general.